# HashMap InputStream / Scanner Server Problems

Tags: java, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I'm making a client/server program for a computer science class.

The idea is that we have a server program that takes a list of console commands, performs them, and returns a response via Input / Output streams. Because of the formatting of the commands, I have to check for whitespaces and digits and split the strings accordingly (which I've done). The problem appears to be in the retrieval of the command from the InputStream.

Commands that should be accepted:

> put [string] [int]
>   - this should store a string (key) and int (value) in the HashMap
>
> get [string]
>   - this should return the int associated with this string
>
> keyset
>   - return all keys
>
> values
>   - return all values
>
> mappings
>   - return all mappings
>
> bye
>   - quit the client
>
> help
>   - doesn't do anything yet, but will list all commands and their syntax

The professor gave us much of the code for the server, but I think there may be errors in it because I keep getting exceptions on the Scanner. See server code below:

```
    package mapserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MapServer
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
       ServerSocket serverSocket = new  ServerSocket(50000);
       while (true)
       {
           Socket activeSock = serverSocket.accept();
           Thread th = new Thread(new MapServerThread(activeSock));
           th.start();
       }
    }    
}

class MapServerThread implements Runnable
{
    private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    private Socket sock;
    public MapServerThread(Socket s)
    {
       sock = s; 

       List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("aaa a", "b", "a");
       for (String str : strs)
       {
           map.put(str, str.length());
       }
    }    

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = 
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(out, true);

            // welcome message
            writer.println("Welcome to the map service.");

            String inputLine = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputLine);
                String fullLine = 
                        sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
                writer.println(fullLine);

                int cmdLoc = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k <fullLine.length(); k++)
                {
                    if (fullLine.charAt(k)==' ');
                    {
                        cmdLoc = k;
                    }
                }

                String cmd;
                if (cmdLoc == 0) 
                {
                    cmd = fullLine;
                    writer.println(cmd);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd = fullLine.substring(0, cmdLoc+1);
                    writer.println(cmd);
                }

                int startloc = cmd.length() + 1;
                switch(cmd)
                {
                    case "put":
                        int intlocation = startloc;
                        for (int k = 0; k < fullLine.length(); k++)
                        {
                            if (Character.isDigit(fullLine.charAt(k)))
                            {
                                intlocation = k;
                            }
                        }

                        // if the int is located at the beginning, the format
                        // is wrong. Let the user know
                        if (intlocation == startloc)
                        {
                            writer.println("Invalid entry. Correct format "
                                    + "is \"put <string> <integer>\"");
                        }

                        // Split the user's entry for putting
                        else
                        {
                            String stringToPut = 
                                    fullLine.substring(startloc, intlocation+1);
                            int intToPut = 
                                    Integer.parseInt(fullLine.substring(intlocation));
                            map.put(stringToPut, intToPut);
                            writer.println("Ok!");
                        }

                        continue;

                    case "get": 
                        int returnvalue = 
                                map.get(fullLine.substring(startloc));
                        writer.println(returnvalue);
                        continue;

                    case "keyset": 
                        String result = map.keySet().toString();
                        writer.println(result);
                        continue;

                    case "values" :
                        String result1 = map.values().toString();
                        writer.println(result1);
                        continue;

                    case "mappings" : 
                        writer.println(map.size());
                        map.forEach(
                                     (k, v) -> 
                                        { writer.println( k + " " + v);}
                                    );                        
                        continue;

                    case "bye" : 
                        writer.println("See you later.");
                        sock.shutdownOutput();
                        sock.close();
                        return;

                    case "help" :
                        continue;
                    default :
                        writer.println("Not a recognized command");

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

    }    
}
```

I'm almost 100% sure the problem is in the server program, as I've been testing it with Telnet. I've tried using the BufferedReader directly instead of the scanner, but the server appears to be getting blank strings. Does anyone have any ideas? I've been fiddling with it for a couple of hours now and I just can't figure it out.

The Problem in a nutshell:

After I login, the server throws:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at mapserver.MapServerThread.run(MapServer.java:67)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and I can't figure out why. If i don't use the scanner, for some reason the server is receiving blank input, regardless of what i type.

Here's what the correct interaction should look like:

```
Welcome to the MapService Client
Enter the IP address of the server: localhost
Please wait while I connect you...
Welcome to the map service.
Map service>mappings
3
a 1
b 1
aaa a 5
Map service>put North Central College 2014
Ok.
Map service>keyset
[a, b, aaa a, North Central College]
Map service>get North Central     College 
2014
Map service>help
7
help
get key
put key value
values
keyset
mappings
bye
Map service>values
[1, 1, 5, 2014]
Map service>bye
See you later.
```

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the problem is

Comment: I edited it to add a bit more

Comment: I fixed the substring errors. Thanks for pointing that out. I'm still getting the exception after the first command.

Comment: Please outline exactly, what should be written to the outstream.

Comment: Added what it should look like from the client's perspective

Comment: Note that I've added some prints in the code for debugging purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is broken, because it's trying to parse the same line twice:

```
String inputLine = null;
while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) //#1

//...

String fullLine =sc.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");//#2
```

You can fix that particular piece with:

```
String fullLine =inputLine.toLowerCase().trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

If you receive a blank inputLine for whatever reason, you can skip it with:

```
if(inputLine.trim().size()==0){
    continue;//invokes the next loop iteration
}
```

**EDIT:**

I rewrote the class and tried to split up the parts to make it easier to grasp. Please give a feedback even though you marked it resolved:

```
class MapServerThread implements Runnable {

    private enum Commands {
        PUT("(put)\\s(\\S+)\\s(\\d)"),
        //add all your commands here and give an approriate regular expression
        UNKNOWN(".+");

        private final String pattern;

        Commands(String regexPattern) {
            pattern = regexPattern;
        }

        private static Commands parseCommand(String s) {
            Commands result = UNKNOWN;

            s = s.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

            for (Commands command : values()) {
                if (command != UNKNOWN && command.pattern.matches(s)) {
                    result = command;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    private Socket sock;

    public MapServerThread(Socket s) {
        sock = s;

        List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("aaa a", "b", "a");
        for (String str : strs) {
            map.put(str, str.length());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);

            writer.println("Welcome to the map service.");

            String inputLine = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine().trim()) != null) {
                Commands command = Commands.parseCommand(inputLine);

                writer.println(command.name());

                execute(command, inputLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void execute(Commands command, String inputLine) {

        switch (command) {
            case PUT:
                String[] args = inputLine.split(" ");
                map.put(args[1], Integer.parseInt(args[2]));
                break;
            //handle the other commands accordingly
            default:
                // notify about an error
                break;

        //
        // get [string] - this should return the int associated with this string
        //
        // keyset - return all keys
        //
        // values - return all values
        //
        // mappings - return all mappings
        //
        // bye - quit the client
        //
        // help - doesn't do anything yet, but will list all commands and their
        // syntax

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This eliminated the error, but now it's sending a blank command after completion of the entered command, resulting in a return of the default switch case.

Comment: Yes i kept on reading your code. Iam "fascinated" what is written there. Give me a minute.

Comment: Looks like there are more problems than I realized. For some reason my loop to find the first blank is consistently returning 1, resulting in cmd always being 3 characters long

Comment: Fixed that. Rogue semi-colon. It looks like everything is working except I get a null pointer exception when I'm using "get"

Comment: Fixed that. What a mess. Thanks for your help. I think it'll be okay from here. Code just seems like a mess at this point. I'm new!